# ssh & script problem

Tags: linux, ssh, logging, putty

I am having a strange problem while doing **ssh**. I am not sure where the term **Unmatched `** is coming from. What I need to do is run **script** that logs information of what I am doing on the terminal to text file. After ssh -

```
Sun Microsystems Inc.   SunOS 5.8       Generic Patch   October 2001
This is /etc/motd, last updated 3 Feb 2003.

To learn about the UCS system and other aspects of computing at UL-Lafayette
visit our home page http://helpdesk.louisiana.edu/ .

For more information about system use, contact the Help Desk, Stephens
Hall, Room 201, 482-5516 (x25516), during normal UL office hours; or send
e-mail to helpdesk@louisiana.edu.


ATTENTION:
Unsecure Telnet and FTP will be turned off soon.
Please make arrange to use ssh or sftp.
Putty(telnet) and WinSCP(ftp) would be a good replacement.


Unmatched `
d13.ucs.louisiana.edu% bash
bash-2.04$ script -a myInformation.txt
Script started, file is myInformation.txt
Unmatched `
d13.ucs.louisiana.edu%
```

When I tried to start the script with name **myInformation.txt**, you can see the message I am getting - `Script started, file is myInformation.txt`. But again I am getting that message **Unmatched `** and is coming out of **bash**, as you can notice. What is the problem ? Any insights suggested would be very great.

Note: file with name **myInformation.txt** is being created but nothing goes in to it. As I have even tried running certain commands like `ls` and then exited the script with **ctrl+d**. But when I open the file, nothing is there.

---

**.cshrc**

```
`# @(#)cshrc 1.11 89/11/29 SMI
if ( `uname -s` == "Linux") then
# /etc/csh.{cshrc,login} set the csh and tcsh environments for Linux
# We just modify a few here:
    set history=20 savehist=20
    exit 0
endif

umask 027

# add here additional directories
set lpath = ()

set path = (~ ~/bin $lpath /usr/local/bin /usr/ccs/bin /usr/dt/bin /usr/openwin/bin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/ucb .)

unset lpath
set noclobber

# Comment out the next line if you WANT core dumps (to debug via dbx,adb,gdb...)
limit coredumpsize 0
# An alternative to the above is to symlink ~/core to /dev/null ....
# Note that a core file can put you over quota, necessitating a command-line
# login [pick from the CDE Options menu] to be able to remove it.

if ( $?prompt == 0) exit
# Put here cmds suitable just for interactive c-shells

set history=20 savehist=20 time=10 autologout=28800
#set ignoreeof
set filec
set notify

#alias ls       'ls -F'
alias mail      mailx

alias nissql /pkgs2/mysql/bin/mysql -h calvados.ucs.louisiana.edu -u cs4601d -p cs4601_d
```

**.login**

```
# @(#)local.login 1.5     98/10/03 SMI

if (`uname -s` == "Linux") then
    exit 0
endif

if (! $?DT ) then
# Insert HERE and commands that are interactive, or alter the terminal
# characteristics.  Thus, they will be bypassed if you start CDE and your
# .dtprofile invokes .login.  Also remember /etc/.login is run first
# by non-CDE logins, and already sets some terminal characteristics.
# -- jpd@usl.edu
    stty -istrip
endif

#         environment variables

#setenv EXINIT 'set sh=/bin/csh sw=4 ai report=2'
#setenv MORE '-c'
#setenv PRINTER lw
setenv RNINIT '-I -e -m -S -i=11 -N -/ -h +hdate +hlines +hfrom -hdate-'
setenv LESS mQ
#setenv PRDEPT nnnn
setenv PAGER /usr/local/bin/less
#setenv EDITOR /usr/local/bin/emacs
setenv MANPATH /usr/local/man:/usr/local/perl/man:/usr/dt/man:/usr/openwin/man:/usr/man
#setenv AB2_DEFAULTSERVER http://pineau.ucs.louisiana.edu:8888/
setenv AB2_DEFAULTSERVER http://docs.sun.com:80/
setenv H_SPELL /dev/null

#
# if possible, start the windows system.  Give user a chance to bail out
# To enable attempting openwin, set try_openwin=1 in the line below:
set try_openwin=0
if ( `tty` == "/dev/console" && $try_openwin) then

    if ( "$TERM" == "sun" || "$TERM" == "sun-color" || "$TERM" == "AT386" ) then

            if ( ${?OPENWINHOME} == 0 ) then
                    setenv OPENWINHOME /usr/openwin
            endif

            echo ""
            echo -n "Starting OpenWindows in 5 seconds (type Control-C to interrupt)"
            sleep 5
            echo ""
            $OPENWINHOME/bin/openwin
            clear           # get rid of annoying cursor rectangle
            echo -n "Automatically logging out (type Control-C to interrupt)"
            sleep 5
            logout          # logout after leaving windows system

    endif

endif
unset try_openwin
```

Comment: you probably have something wrong in one of your `.bashrc`, `.bash_profile`, `.profile` or other.

Comment: @Mat I don't see any of those existing even when I do `ls -al`

Comment: what other dotfiles do you have?

Comment: @Mat - `.`, `..`, `.TTauthority`, `.Xauthority`, `.bash_history`, `.cshrc`, `.dt`, `.dtprofile`, `.forward`, `.history`, `.iiim`, `.login`, `.mozilla`, `.mysql_history`, `.openwebmail`, `.opera`, `.qt`, `.recently-used`, `.ssh`, `.staroffice8`, `.vacation.msg`

Comment: probably `.login` or `.cshrc`. can you post them if they are not huge?

Comment: @Mat Added the two files. I only have the problem and my friends were able to log into and run **srcipt** with no problem. Thanks.

Comment: unless this is a copy/paste error, the very first char of `.cshrc` is wrong. remove it.

Comment: @Mat - That was the error. It did exist in my `.cshrc` and removed it. It is working now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extra ` seems to be right there in the very beginning of your .cshrc.

...except of course if you *are* running bash as you say. What's the output of `ps`?

Comment: @IIKa - Saved the day. Thanks.